# Google exchange token does not return id_token

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, access-token

I am calling google `/oauth2/v4/token` with my request, looks like this formatted:

```
code: 4/zxxxxxxxxxxx_Kdzxxxxxxxxn5hMzQkOoIdzLtys
response_type: id_token
scope: openid
client_id: xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com
client_secret: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
grant_type: authorization_code
```

and the response is this:

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.Ci81AzruWyxhmn8WKadpzPEmhCDPmQPSxHZogyd_ZIT0g-VMgzY5PZFk4i-CMe9lUw",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": 3583
}
```

However, I also require `id_token` adding `scope` and `response_type` did not fix the issue. I tried all different scopes and response types and neither of them worked.

Answer (score 0):

The scope `openid` is not enough. You should add the scope `email` for example.
These scope must be set during the authorization redirection. They are not mandatory when requesting the access token.

Moreover, the `response_type` parameter is not needed when you send a request against the server.

Comment: But what if we dont use redirection?

Comment: To get a code, you must use the `code` response type which uses redirections. I maybe the `authorization_code` grant type is not what you need.